# continue foreach loop from a specific point within array

Tags: php

I have an array containing lots of hours:

```
$hours = array(
    '06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', 
    '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', 
    '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', 
    '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30',
    '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30', '00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', 
    '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30', 
);
```

I'd like to begin looping through from a specific point e.g. '12:30'.

I have tried to use 'continue' (as below), but this is ignored. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
     if ($hour == '12:30') continue;
     echo $hour . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Can you debug when `$hour` is '12:30'? What does the if block result to when it compares '12:30' to '12:30'?

Comment: So your goal is to output all times from `12:30` forward, (or not including 12:30)?

Comment: Ok, well your `for` loop says in English, "go through each hour in the array. If hour is '12:30', continue to the next iteration, ignoring everything else in the loop. Otherwise, echo the hour and a line break."  It is **not** skipping everything until 12:30

Comment: Will the value ever occur more than once?

Comment: No the value shouldn't occur more than once as it's in 24 hr times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the key referring to '12:30', and, if found, loop over the $hours array starting at that key.

```
if ( $key = array_search('12:30', $hours) ) {
  for ( ; $key < count($hours); $key++ ) {
    print $hours[$key] . '<br>'; 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$hours = array(
    '06:00', '06:30', '07:00', '07:30', '08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', 
    '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30', '13:00', '13:30', 
    '14:00', '14:30', '15:00', '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30', 
    '18:00', '18:30', '19:00', '19:30', '20:00', '20:30', '21:00', '21:30',
    '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30', '00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', 
    '02:00', '02:30', '03:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30', '05:00', '05:30', 
);

$start = array_search('12:30',$hours);

foreach($hours as $key => $hour) {
    if($key < $start)
        continue;

    print "$hour\n";
}
```

Or as suggested in comments (and this is faster)

```
$start = array_search('12:30',$hours);

for($i = $start; $i < count($hours); $i++) {
    print $hours[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Probably better to just use an incremental `for` loop starting from `$start` up to `count($hours)` instead of bothering with `continue`, looping over stuff which isn't needed.

Comment: ..but yes, `array_search()` is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
if ($hour < '12:30') {
    continue;
}
```

Your code just skips that one time, it doesn't skip all the ones before it.

Another way to do it is to get the position of the desired hour, and use a normal `for` loop:

```
foreach ($i = array_search('12:30', $hours); $i !== false && $i < count($hours); $i++) {
    $hour = $hours[$i];
    echo $hour . "<br";
}
```